# For loop for creating dataframes from a list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, cbind

I have a list which contains an arbitrary number of 25 data frames. So i want to create 25 data frames from the content of the list and then bind them into one. In essence for the list called x i want to:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(x[1])
dfi <- as.data.frame(x[i])
df.final = cbind(df1,dfi)
```

which works fine. Here is what i tried without any success:

```
   for (i in 1:length(x){
     df[i] = as.data.frame(x[i])
     df.final = cbind(df[i]+1)
     }
```

Any help we appreciated since i'm quite stuck

Comment: Have a look at the functions `Reduce()` and `data.table::rbindlist()` (if you want to `rbind` instead of `cbind`). You can either use `df_final <- Reduce(cbind, x)` if `x` contains `data.frame`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `reduce` function from `purrr` with the `bind_cols` function from `dplyr`

Essentially you want to pass your list of dataframes into `reduce`, which iterates through the function you provide, which in this case is `bind_cols`. This will first bind `df1` with `df2`, then the resulting dataframe with `df3`, etc.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
  x = c(1, 2, 3),
  y = c(2, 3, 4)
)

df2 <- tibble(
  a = c("a", "b", "c"),
  b = c("x", "y", "z")
)

df3 <- tibble(
  a = c("h", "n", "c"),
  b = c("q", "j", "z")
)

dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)

result <- dfs %>%
  reduce(bind_cols)

result

# A tibble: 3 x 6
      x     y a     b     a1    b1   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1     2 a     x     h     q    
2     2     3 b     y     n     j    
3     3     4 c     z     c     z
```

Comment: You could use only `bind_cols(dfs)` (without `reduce`) and obtain the same result.